# MQTT Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mqtt, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to set up Spark Streaming to read a MQTT source, but it launches an exception when I receive the second message.

I have the following code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt._
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ForeachWriter, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // Read text from socket
    val lines = spark.readStream.format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider").option("topic", "measurement").option("username", "spark").option("password", "******").load("tcp://10.0.0.129:1883").as[(String, Timestamp)]

    val query = lines.writeStream.format("console").start

    query.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

And I observe the following exception when I receive a second message:

```
17/01/16 16:18:33 ERROR StreamExecution: Query query-1 terminated with error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTTextStreamSource.commit(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Offset;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:142)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for query-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTTextStreamSource.commit(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Offset;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch(StreamExecution.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:142)
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Query query-1 terminated with exception: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTTextStreamSource.commit(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Offset;)V
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:142)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTTextStreamSource.commit(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Offset;)V
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:359)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(StreamExecution.scala:358)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:358)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:345)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$constructNextBatch(StreamExecution.scala:345)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:656)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:208)
  ... 1 more
```

Did anybody have this problem?

Comment: Which version of Spark and MQTT are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  Spark 2.0.2 and MQTT 3.1

Comment: Does MQTT 3.1 support Spark 2.0.2?

Comment: I have no idea how to check it.
I am using the library Eclipse Paho, which supports MQTT 3.1 and MQTT 3.1.1, and I have already tried with Spark 2.1.1 without success.

Comment: Are you providing MQTT manually on the cluster or are you compiling to an uber JAR? Looks like there's a mismatch with the versions.

Comment: Do you mean the server? I am manually running VerneMQ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your spark-MQTT jar the same version of your spark? it's possible that different versions cause these problems. I had a similar problem when using spark 1.6 from Cloudera Express. After upgrading it to the same version the problem was solved

Comment: Great! Just figured out that I was using Spark 2.1.0 and the MQTT jar was built for version 2.0.1.